# Passing data from android studio to php

Tags: php, mysql, json, android-studio

I amm new in android. I want to get value of my id using json to my php server 
so I can get all data i want from my database.

This is query I want to do

```
$query1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jadwal_matakuliah WHERE nim_mhs ='$id'");
```

**my php code**

```
<?php
     include "koneksi.php";

     $username = $_POST["id"];

     $query1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jadwal_matakuliah WHERE nim_mhs ='$id'");

     if($query)
     {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
             $flag[]=$row;
        }
        print(json_encode($flag));
     }
     mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**my android code**

```
    String id, username;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";

    String urladdress="http://10.0.2.2/multi/menu_mhs.php";
    String[] name;
    String[] jam;
    String[] email;
    String[] imagepath;
    ListView listView;
    BufferedInputStream is;
    String line=null;
    String result=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lview);
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy((new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build()));
        collectData();

        CustomListView customListView=new CustomListView(this,name,email,imagepath,jam);
        listView.setAdapter(customListView);

//        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MHS");
        txt_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
        txt_username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        btn_logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(Login.my_shared_preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        id = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
        username = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_USERNAME);
        txt_id.setText("" + id);
        txt_username.setText("( " + username +" )");

    }

    private void collectData() {

        //Connection
        try {

            URL url = new URL(urladdress);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            is = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        //content
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

//JSON
        try {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject jo = null;

            name = new String[ja.length()];
            jam = new String[ja.length()];
            email = new String[ja.length()];
            imagepath = new String[ja.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i <= ja.length(); i++) {
                jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                name[i] = jo.getString("nama_matakuliah");
                email[i] = jo.getString("dosen");
                imagepath[i] = jo.getString("photo");
                jam[i] = jo.getString("jadwal");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Comment: So the PHP is running on a web server and Android code runs on the phone?

Comment: @Nelles for a while.. im just running android code on emulator and the php on local server

Answer (score 0):

You can send the id as a query parameter with your URL,
ie if  your URL is `example.com/hello` then
you can call it as `example.com/hello?id=your_id`